# php regex to js regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to convert this php regex to js regex, to get same result.
Please, check live here..

```
/(\{(?>[^{}]+|(?1))*\})/m
```

want matches like this:
[image]

https://regex101.com/r/EYhxny/1

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question. We shouldn't have to head to external links just to understand the problem.

Comment: hope, this make more clear about my request.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, javascript PCRE doesn't have recursive parameters ( (?1) (?R), etc). But you can try use loop for all matching.